# Implementing Profanity filter jQuery library in AngularJS Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to implement a [jQuery library](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter) that will filter out profanity through an AngularJS directive.  I'm fairly new to AngularJS so I'm not sure if it's something dumb that I've overlooked, but I can't seem to get the filtering to work.  This is my directive (as part of a longer chain):

```
.directive("censorSwearWords", [
    () => {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                $(element).profanityFilter({
                    externalSwears: 'swearWords.json'
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the element that I'm attempting to apply it to:

```
<textarea class="messageTextArea" rows="15" readonly="readonly" censor-swear-words>{{message.body}}</textarea>
```

However, the filtering isn't occurring.  I believe the profanity reader is trying to filter `{{message.body}}` rather than the text within.  Aside from using the timeout service, is there a way with AngularJS to ensure that it actually reads the contents of `{{message.body}` once it's been rendered fully?

Comment: You need to use `ng-model` on textarea and work with the ngModel controller in your directive

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the $applyAsync on [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).  It was introduced as an alternative to wrapping these sorts of calls in $timeout.  However, there is no way to avoid doing one of those two options.  Angular has no way of knowing that the jQuery plugin has modified a value(if at all) and you need to manually tell Angular that it should digest the page again for changes.